# Crash while going back from fullscreen video to webview.java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am getting `"java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first android"` error for the below code.

From the log it is seen that the error is seen in the line. `setContentView(mWebPageParentView)` in  `public void onHideCustomView()` API.

Please Help me to Resolve this that the earliest.

//Initial declarations.

```
private WebChromeClient mWebChromeClient = null;
private View mFullScreenVideoView;
private RelativeLayout mWebPageParentView;
private FrameLayout mFullScreenViewContainer = null;
private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mFullScreenVideoViewCallback;
```

// code

```
@Override
public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback  callback) {     

if (mFullScreenVideoView != null) {
callback.onCustomViewHidden();
return;
}

// The below line was missing while writing here. 
mWebPageParentView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyt_main);
// The above line was missing while writing here. 
mWebPageParentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);                        
mFullScreenViewContainer = new FrameLayout(BrowserActivity.this);
mFullScreenViewContainer.setLayoutParams(LayoutParameters);
view.setLayoutParams(LayoutParameters);
mFullScreenViewContainer.addView(view);
mFullScreenVideoView = view;
mFullScreenVideoViewCallback = callback;
mFullScreenViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
setContentView(mFullScreenViewContainer);
}

@Override
public void onHideCustomView() {
 if (mFullScreenVideoView == null) {
return;
  } else {
   // Hide the custom view.  
mFullScreenVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mFullScreenViewContainer.removeView(mFullScreenVideoView);
mFullScreenViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

mFullScreenViewContainer = null;
mFullScreenVideoViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
// Show the content view.  
    mWebPageParentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    setContentView(mWebPageParentView);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to remove you video view `mFullScreenViewContainer` from parent view and then you can use `setContentView()` for `mWebPageParentView` on same parent.

Do something like this :

```
ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) mFullScreenViewContainer.getParent();
int index = parentView .indexOfChild(mFullScreenViewContainer);
parentView .removeView(mFullScreenViewContainer);

parentView .addView(mWebPageParentView);
```

`index` if want to remove using index. And

Comment: Check my answer again with updation

Comment: I checked your answer again. But the error remained the same.
What is the use of index? mViewParent in the sample here mean mFullScreenViewContainer? can parent.addView(mNewView_U_want_to_add) view can be replaced by mFullScreenViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)?

Comment: The issue of java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must call removeView() on the child's parent first is resolved when I changed the mWebPageParentView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.webpage) to mWebPageParentView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyt_main); However, When I come back from the fullscreen, the webpage is not seen rather only the layout is seen without any content. @Harish Godara: Can you please help me in this?. Thanks for the earlier help.